# How to display error message in flex

Tags: actionscript, mxml

I am new to this Adobe flex development.Right now I am working on the application and in my mxml form I have to place 2 fields.

one is Radio button(option (yes ,no) )and another one is text box(name), and the requirement is:

- when the user selects yes then the name field should enable otherwise it should be disable.
  The validation rules are:

  1. if the user selects yes and he would not enter any value(textbox is empty) then we should display error message that `"value is required"`
  2. if the user selects no and the text filed has some value then first he has to delete the contents in the textfiled then only select `'no'`.

someone please help me and give me some code sample.That would be great help for me.

Answer (score 2):

put  this code in your `MXML`application and run..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           width="567" height="206" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" initialize="application1_initializeHandler(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function application1_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {


        }

        protected function rd1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            if(!t1.enabled)
            {
                t1.enabled=true;
            }
            else if(t1.text=="" && t1.enabled)
             {
               Alert.show("Value is required in text box");
            }
            else
                t1.enabled=true;
        }

        protected function rd2_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        { 
            t1.text=null
            t1.enabled =false;

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:TextInput x="132" y="41" id="t1"/>
     <s:RadioButton x="162" y="91" label="Yes" id="rd1" groupName="select"          click="rd1_clickHandler(event)"/>
 <s:RadioButton x="211" y="91" label="No" id="rd2"  groupName="select" click="rd2_clickHandler(event)" />
<s:Label x="79" y="45" text="Name"/>
    </s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom mxml control based on TitleWindow and us PopupManager to show it on display.